# Why am I getting "undefined method `start_with?'"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails project that I've been updating to the latest version of Ruby and Rails.  When I run `rake assets:precompile` I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for /bootstrap-editable\/.*\.(?:png|gif)$/:Regexp (NoMethodError)

      str.start_with?("file://".freeze) && parse_asset_uri(str) ? true : false
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sprockets-4.2.1/lib/sprockets/uri_utils.rb:78:in `valid_asset_uri?'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sprockets-4.2.1/lib/sprockets/resolve.rb:27:in `resolve'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sprockets-4.2.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:79:in `find_asset'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sprockets-4.2.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:88:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sprockets-4.2.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sprockets-4.2.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `to_a'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sprockets-4.2.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in find'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:24:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:48:in `block in synchronize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:48:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:48:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:22:in `execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promise.rb:564:in `block in realize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:352:in `run_task'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:343:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `loop'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `catch'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `block in create_worker'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have the latest version of `bootstrap-editable`.  What else could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[bootstrap-editable](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/bootstrap-editable-rails) is 10 years old, it's time to let it go or fork and fix it. Specifically, this part is the issue:
*https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/bootstrap-editable-rails/blob/master/lib/bootstrap-editable-rails.rb#L12*

```rb
app.config.assets.precompile << %r(bootstrap-editable/.*\.(?:png|gif)$)
```

You can't have Regexp for locating precompiled assets, this has been replaced with `manifest.js` in *Sprockets v4*.

> ...if you were previously using regexp or proc values, they won't work at all with Sprockets 4, and if you try you'll get an exception raised that looks like `NoMethodError: undefined method 'start_with?'`

*https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/main/UPGRADING.md#manifestjs*